# How can I increment int by 1 when calling a method from another Class

Tags: c#, .net, integer

I would like to implement the following idea in C# but I am stuck with this and cannot move on.
I want to create more objects from the Class Something and always when I call the method I_Frame I would like to increase the sequence number by 1 (I am trying to test it with a button).

```
  public class Something
    {
        private int sequenceNumber;

        public int SequenceNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return this.sequenceNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                this.sequenceNumber = value;
            }

        }

        public int I_FRAME(ref byte[] IFrame)
        {

            IFrame[0] = (byte)((sequenceNumber);
            IFrame[1] = 0x00

            sequenceNumber=sequenceNumber + 1 % 32768;
            return sequenceNumber;

        }
```

and this is my button code.

```
public partial class VlastniTCP : Form
    {
       byte[] testbyte = new byte[2];

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            Something Test = new Something();
            Test.I_Frame(ref testbyte);
            textbox1.Text = testbyte[0];

        }
   }
```

I would be happy for every advice or explonation how to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You create a new class instance each time the button is pressed. Since you assign the sequence number before you increment it, you'll only ever get zero. Also, storing an `int` in a byte-sized array will only work for so long. Also, assuming the limit is as intended you'll probably want to do `sequenceNumber=(sequenceNumber + 1) % 32768;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating a new `Something` every time you click the button. `Something.sequenceNumber` defaults to zero whenever you create a new one. Your options are:

Option 1: Use the same instance of something every time:

```
    public partial class VlastniTCP : Form
    {
        byte[] testbyte = new byte[2];
        private Something test;

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            test ??= new Something();
            test.I_FRAME(ref testbyte);
            textbox1.Text = testbyte[0];

        }
    }
```

Option 2: Keep track of the last used sequenceNumber:

```
    public class Something
    {
        private static int lastSequenceNumber;

        public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }

        public int I_FRAME(ref byte[] IFrame)
        {
            var sequenceNumber = (lastSequenceNumber + 1) % 32768;
            lastSequenceNumber = sequenceNumber;
            SequenceNumber = sequenceNumber;

            IFrame[0] = (byte)sequenceNumber;
            IFrame[1] = 0x00;

            return sequenceNumber;

        }
    }
```